# How to get Hover Event to Work with Free jqGrid 4.13

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid

I have an image that when I hover over it should change the height and width of the image.

```
<img title="Pax Layout Guide" class="modified20 paxlayoutguide floatright" src="/QMSWebApp/Images/paxorientation.png">

<head>
<style>
    .paxlayoutguide{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        width: 20px;

    }

    .paxlayoutguide:hover{
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        width: 600px;
        z-index: 600000;
    }
</style>
```

This was working until I installed and started using the free jqGrid 4.13.

Is there something in the jqgrid css that is overriding my hover event?

Update to show more code:

```
<head>
<style>
.paxlayoutguide{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        width: 20px;

}
.paxlayoutguide:hover{
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        width: 600px;
        z-index: 600000;
    }
</style>
</head>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>

<div class="hide">
    <INPUT type="text" class="callingcontrol" size="1"  value="${aclcomponentObj.componentcategory}">
    <INPUT type="text" class="nextcomponentindex" size="1" value="${aclcomponentObj.componentindex}">
    <INPUT type="text" class="cpaxcount" size="1" value="${aclcomponentObj.paxcount}">
    <INPUT type="text" class="currentpaxselected" size="1" value="">
    <INPUT type="text" class="lastmanualitem" size="15" value="">       
</div>

<div class="miscdisplayheader">
    <img title="Close" class="modified20  aclgeneratorcomponentlistFormClose floatright" src="/QMSWebApp/Images/close[1].jpg">
    <img title="Pax Layout Guide" class="modified20 paxlayoutguide floatright" src="/QMSWebApp/Images/paxorientation.png">
    Component Category: ${aclcomponentObj.componentcategory}<br>
    Seat Assy: ${aclseatassyObj.seatassy} &nbsp;&nbsp; ${aclseatassyObj.seatassy_description}
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Which relation has the image to free jqGrid 4.13? Do you use it somewhere inside of custom formatter or inside of navigator button or somewhere else (in edit/search form for example)? **Could you provide the demo, which reproduce the problem?** Which version of free jqGrid you use: 4.13.0, ..., 4.13.4 or 4.13.5-pre from GitHub?

Comment: @OlegIt is really not in the jqgrid(4.13.3) code. I just mentioned that if stopped functioning after I upgraded the jqgrid recently. I will post more of the code to try and clarify.

Comment: You last code contains no reference to jqGrid CSS of JavaScript. You should understand, that I can help you to find any CSS conflicts only if I can reproduce the problem. You should prepare the demo (in JSFiddle, for example), where including free jqGrid CSS or JS break some functionality. Having the demo one can use Developer Tools of Chrome or Internet Explorer to see which CSS properties will be overwritten by some CSS rules. I can't help you without the demo.

Comment: @Oleg Sorry it was my fault. I had add a !important to width and height of an associated class.

Comment: No problem! Is the problem is solved now? Fine!